# Flutter Internationalization: translate list items (in JSON?)

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, internationalization

I have this widget in Flutter/Dart:

```
  Widget _buildTimeRow() {
    var keys = widget.place!.openingTime.keys.toList();
    var length = widget.showFull! ? keys.length : min(keys.length, 5);
    return Container(
        child: Column(
            children: List.generate(
                length,
                (int index) => Container(
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: 100,
                            child: Text(keys[index],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                                child: Text(widget.place!.openingTime[keys[index]] ?? "",
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))));
  }
```

The problem is that I can not translate the `Text(keys[index]` part.

I tried adding this:

```
                  if (keys[index] == 1) ...[ // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and so on.
                    Text(Localized.of(context)!.trans(LocalizedKey.NewWord) ?? "",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
```

This does not work. How could I get it to work so that I can translate the outcome of the list items (in the index) to be translated?

Is this even possible?

Comment: It is really hard to tell what your actual problem is, since you are referencing multiple classes and methods that are not part of the provided code snippet. It also looks like there is a ton of stuff that is *not* relevant to your problem in there.

Can you update the code to include a _complete_ example of your problem, without any of the "fluff"?

Comment: The question is not really clear. Are you using some packages for handling translation? What does "keys" list contains? What's the result you are trying to achieve? Please add some detail

Answer (score 0):

I created a Library that might be able to help you. It doesn't translate but you can easily create multi-lingual UI with it by storing static text values(the same text on different languages).

[Try translatable_text_field package](https://pub.dev/packages/translatable_text_field)

[My multi-lingual apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub%3Arawware&c=apps)

Hope this helps

Comment: How is this different than internationalization? Can you explain?